Setting Recipient and Regarding Field When Replying to an E-mail in Dynamics 365 CRM
I am working with Dynamics 365 CRM and need some assistance with handling e-mails in the interactive experience form. Specifically, I am trying to reply to an e-mail directly from the timeline.
Here’s what I have achieved so far:
I can modify the sender’s address to a default e-mail using JavaScript.
Our own system sends the initial e-mail, so the sender is our own domain. When replying, the e-mail address defaults to this. I have a workflow that parses the e-mail and creates the contact and case according to customer values.
However, I am encountering two issues:
Recipient Address: I want to automatically set the recipient to the Case’s customer e-mail address when replying. Currently, I have to set this manually.
Regarding Field: The ‘Regarding’ field is empty when replying, and I need it to be automatically set to the related case.
I'm not sure how to proceed as I'm not experienced.
Here's my default e-mail JS:
function setSender(executionContext, entityType, name, ID){
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext()
    // Set the "From" field
    var lookup = new Array();
    lookup[0] = new Object();
    lookup[0].id = ID; 
    lookup[0].name = name; 
    lookup[0].entityType = entityType;
    formContext.getAttribute("from").setValue(lookup);
    console.log("Default e-mail is set");
}


